# Acquire Token to access Azure Resources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I have used the ADAL.js for acquiring token for Azure Resources.

```
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.15/js/adal.min.js"></script>
```

I have written the following code in order to do so:

```
var endpoints = {
    "https://management.core.windows.net": "https://management.core.windows.net"
};
var config = {
    clientId: '634c7103-b43e-4384-b345-db0116058ac3',
    endpoints: endpoints,
};
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);

function login() {
    authContext.popUp = true;
    authContext.login();
    authContext.handleWindowCallback();
};

function clickme() {
    var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
    console.log(user);

    authContext.acquireToken('https://management.core.windows.net', function (error, token) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(token);
    });
};
```

Now when I have called clickme() after login, got the following error message: **Token renewal operation failed due to timeout**. Am I missing something ?

My final goal is to create a web application that can list all the subscription, resource group and vault corresponding to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that `handleWindowCallback` method is called when AAD sends the response to redirectUri. Whatever code is executed when the redirectUri page is loaded should ensure that `handlewindowcallback` method is called.

Please try below code , it works fine on my side :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.15/js/adal.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var endpoints = {
            "https://management.core.windows.net": "https://management.core.windows.net"
        };
        var config = {
            clientId: 'e333d3fe-a73a-4476-8121-8a57f9a972ca',
            endpoints: endpoints,
        };
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
        authContext.handleWindowCallback();

        function login() {
            authContext.popUp = true;
            authContext.login();
           // authContext.handleWindowCallback();
            var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
            console.log(user);
        };

        function clickme() {
            var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
            console.log(user);

            authContext.acquireToken('https://management.core.windows.net', function (error, token) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(token);
            });
        };
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="clickme()" />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="login" onclick="login()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes it worked. But I don't understand the logic of `handleWindowCallback`. What is this function doing? And suppose I want to call `clickme()` automatically on the successful login, How can I achieve this?

Comment: handleWindowCallback method  saves the token in the cache and calls the callback with the error or token. Above code will automatically call handleWindowCallback in page load

Comment: One can set `authContext.callback = onSuccessLogin` and can define their own callback which will be called by `authContext.login()` as callback.
ProtoType: `function onSuccessLogin(error, token, msg)`